# Is it possible to group multiple objects to suppress them altogether

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping

In Crystal Report I need to suppress multiple objects at the same time based on a condition. But writing a dedicated function for each of them means a waste of time. Is there a way in Crystal Report to put objects into something like a grouping panel so that by just hiding that panel will hide all the objects that are inside it?

Comment: select them all, right click, format objects and write the suppress condition under Suppress X-2 dialog to apply the same condition to all of them

Comment: Oh, man I don't know why I didn't manage to think of that. I ended up selecting 36 elements one by one and edited their suppress formulas :)

Answer (score 1):

To save a little time you can create one formula that results true for your suppression requirements and use that instead of creating a formula for each suppressed field. That way if there are changes you just make them to that formula instead of having to go back to suppression for each.